# Is that possible to use @max in filter in Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

I have an Object, say

```
class Task:Object {
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    dynamic var name:String = ""

    override func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

When I use filter with max.

```
let tasks = realm.allObjects(ofType: Task.self)
let results = tasks.filter(using: "id.@max")
```

I got the error:

> Unable to parse the format string "id.@max".

Then I realized I should use

```
let results = tasks.filter(using: "id == id.@max")
```

Then I got another error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate', reason:
>   'Aggregate operations can only be used on key paths that include an
>   array property'

Now I am wondering what can I do if I want to use @max in filter?

I know I could use `sorted` to get the task with the max id. But I want to know if I could use it with filter.

Comment: I think you should take a look on the NSPredicate Cheatsheet from Realm. There's something about using `@max` on querys: https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

Comment: @Orlando Thank you. Now I know @max can't be use on `id` as its type is not List<T> or something alike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve the task with the largest ID, you can do something like the following:

```
let tasks = realm.allObjects(ofType: Task.self)
let id = tasks.maximumValue(ofProperty: "id") as Int?
let newestTask = realm.object(ofType: Task.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
```

The reason `@max` doesn't work for this purpose is that it evaluates to the maximum value of a property for the members of a collection, but the predicate is evaluated in the context of a each individual item.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is impossible to use @max on `id`. The answer is no. `@max` can only use in List property or something alike, `id` is Int.